# Custom membership provider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am implementing my own membership provider.I used Repository pattern.

```
public interface IMembershipService: IDisposable
{
    void CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string role);
    bool CheckUsernameExist(string username);
    string EncodePassword(string originalPassword,string salt);
    // Some other my admin methods
}
public class MembershipService : IMembershipService
{
    public MembershipService()
    {
    }
    public void ActivateUserAccount(string username, string email)
    {
        // Some validation code
    }
    public void CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string role)
    {
        // Some validation code
    }
   }
```

I did not inherited MembershipProvider. Now, I want to know how to implement GetUser() which return the current logged in user.I have no idea about that.
Second thing, by inheriting MembershipProvider, Can I used GetUser() or some other useful methods? I could not inherit that class as well , if I want to do so.
Please guide me and don't downvote as answer to this question matter me most.
Thanks

Comment: What is your reason for creating a custom membership provider?  This functionality is not as easy as it seems, and 99% of people who do it themselves do it wrong (that is, do it insecurely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are heading in the right track, what you have to do now is have your `MembershipService` implement both `IMembershipService` and `MembershipProvider` then you can do the following:

```
public class MembershipService : MembershipProvider, IMembershipService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRep; // or whatever you are calling your user repository

    public MembershipService()
       : this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>())
    {
    }

    public MembershipService(IUserRepository userRep)
    {
       this._userRep = userRep;
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
    ...
```

Your `IMembershipService` interface should implement all the classes from `MembershipProvider` that you plan on using.
You can then inject your `IMembershipService` into your controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to created your custom ASP.NET Membership provider, you MUST inherit from the abstract MembershipProvider class. If not, it will not fit into the entire ASP.NET Providers model.

> To implement a membership provider, you create a class that inherits
>   the MembershipProvider abstract class from the System.Web.Security
>   namespace. The MembershipProvider abstract class inherits the
>   ProviderBase abstract class from the System.Configuration.Provider
>   namespace, so you must implement the required members of the
>   ProviderBase class as well.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You will need to override all the methods and provide your own data access.
Here's [example code for an ODBC Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library: 
[Code First MembershipProvider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/). Just replace the database queries with calls to your repository.